# Crash for onClick event: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

### Background

I work on an app that got a crash report that doesn't make sense.

The scenario that seems to occur (according to the stackTrace) is that the user clicked on an item on the navigation drawer, which in turn replaced the current fragment being shown on the fragment-container of the activity:

```
...
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_from_left, R.anim.fade_out).replace(R.id.activity_main__fragmentContainer, fragmentToShow).commit(); // <=crash here
...
```

The crash report is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
   at android.support.v4.app.u.w(FragmentManager.java:1365)
   at android.support.v4.app.u.a(FragmentManager.java:1383)
   at android.support.v4.app.j.a(BackStackRecord.java:636)
   at android.support.v4.app.j.a(BackStackRecord.java:615)
```

And then the line I've written, and the click handling (which is really a simple onClickListener).

### The problem

Searching on Google and here, I've found a lot of possible solutions but for different, similar issues.

### The question

The crash itself is quite rare, but I can't find the cause for it.
How could this issue exist?

Could the upgrade of the recent support library (to 22.1.0) have fixed it? The version the app used before is just one version before of it.

I could add a check if the current activity is not being destroyed, but it's just too weird...

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is not complete... I cant say an exact solution...
I think you are calling for the animation before loading the fragment completely...
ie, before inflating the layout file to the containter...
try to call the animation after,

view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

Comment: The fragment itself creates the views via its onCreateView. Is it completely the same? Also, what should be the rest of the code, to replace the previous one?

Comment: Try this code...  FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
ft.replace(fragment_container, new NewFragmentToReplace()); 
ft.commit();

Comment: But is it the same? could it withstand orientation change?